# How to do Ad Integration in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

So, what is ad integration and how to implement in windows phone 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad intergation means allow to run ads in our application. For other Application http://www.admob.com/  and for WP7  http://www.adgac.com/

AdMob provides app developers with a solution to distribute and monetize your apps. All SDKs are designed to take advantage of the unique capabilities of each platform.

Comment: Do admob do WP7? There's a new one called AdGac specific for WP7 which seems to offer more functionality than other ad platforms. Haven't used it myself tho. http://www.adgac.com/

Comment: Actually I was developing small application like city guide, push notification. So , I want to know about ad integration and implementation in our app. While i'm searching in net, I got those answer, then I posted.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides something called the Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 7. I have a short post on the subject here

http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2010/10/microsoft-advertising-sdk-for-windows.html

You can get the Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 7 here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b0f00afc-9709-4cc2-ba2c-57728db6cbd6

Answer (score 2):

AldarIT has a Free (but not Open) Multiple network ad control for WP7 that works well.
http://www.aldarit.com/superads.html

Answer (score 1):

Smatoo has a WP7 one as well.

Had a fair bit of trouble with it though. I disabled location services it still shows up in the manifest. This caused my app to fail certification as i didn't have a policy as to how the location data would be used.